# What to back-up in home partition?

Tags: rsync, backup, home

The hard drive in the notebook I own is quite old. So, I have a habit of doing regular back-ups to avoid losing everything should it fail.

`Rsync` does fine job of backing-up the partition (it is a separate one from `~/` in my case) where I keep my files.

But what to back-up in `~/` partition? Backing-up the whole partition takes considerable amount of time and I can't help but notice that most of this time is spent copying some temporary files like, for example, those of browser cache that are not really needed.

Of course, certain directories can be excluded from syncing in `rsync`. But again which directories except obvious `~/.cache`? It seems certain programs keep the cached stuff in their own sub-directories. Is there a way to back up `~/` smartly?

Comment: You'll need to sort through and exclude what you don't want. The [XDG base dir specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) is supposed to help this problem, but many programs don't respect it.

Comment: Some info here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997 & 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270519/rsync-exclude-a-directory-but-include-a-subdirectory/37219769#37219769

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no universal answer for  this, nor is there is an 'ez mode' default for handling it. Basically everything in your home folder is going to be personal user files and program data and it gets spread around in several places, mainly the `.` dirs like `.config` and `.local`, because there is no standard or enforced rule for apps to follow when it comes to that. Thus, you gotta manually determine what can and cannot be replaced by going through it recursively.

Like you said, there are a couple obvious ones. You mentioned `.cache` and  there may also be `.local/share/trash` and I'd also exclude any web browsers or web apps with a local cache. That should reduce the size considerably. You could also run a `du --all` on your home dir to get an idea of the big things and see how much you can exclude. `du --help`` will give you a bunch of choices for paring it down that way. Good luck.

Comment: I trust this pretty much answers my question. Thank you!